# Parsing data in a foreach statement then adding to listview

Tags: regex, vb.net, parsing, listview, split

I'm trying to parse some string from a web file, and organize the parsed contents into a listview. Well it's not as easy as I thought haha.

This is the string I'm trying to parse

```
array(7) { [0]=> string(1) "0" [1]=> string(5) "hefqn" [2]=> string(23) "SP-Branding SP-Digital " [3]=> string(18) "all hail the hefqn" [4]=> string(11) "rune-server" [5]=> string(6) "tickle" [6]=> string(23) "http://www.prntscr.com" }

array(7) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(6) "hefqn2" [2]=> string(23) "SP-Branding SP-Digital " [3]=> string(18) "2ll hail the hefqn" [4]=> string(11) "rune-server" [5]=> string(6) "tickle" [6]=> string(23) "http://www.prntscr.com" }
```

That's two entries in a database, the first one being the first entry, and the second one being the second entry.

Now the text inside of the above code that I'm trying to get out is this (I will put *** Before and after the text i'm trying to parse)

```
array(7) { [0]=> string(1) "***0***" [1]=> string(5) "***hefqn***" [2]=> string(23) "***Digital***" [3]=> string(18) "***test***" [4]=> string(11) "***rune-server***" [5]=> string(6) "***tickle***" [6]=> string(23) "***http://www.prntscr.com***" }

array(7) { [0]=> string(1) "***1***" [1]=> string(6) "***hefqn2***" [2]=> string(23) "***Branding***" [3]=> string(18) "***test2***" [4]=> string(11) "***rune-server***" [5]=> string(6) "***tickle***" [6]=> string(23) "***http://www.prntscr.com***" }
```

Now while parsing the text, it's in a foreach statement because I'm grabbing multiple database entries, which all have that layout.

The listview would look like this 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqCXA.png

I've been trying to figure this out for an hour now and I cant seem to get it right.

Does anyone have any ideas on how they could do it? Thanks alot!!

PS Here's what I've tried, it adds to each subitem rather then once each row

```
Dim test As New WebClient
  Dim s As String = test.DownloadString(TheStringIPosted)
  For Each myMatch1 As Match In New Regex("""(.*?)""", RegexOptions.None).Matches(s)
  Dim lvi As ListViewItem

  lvi = ListView1.Items.Add(myMatch1.Groups.Item(1).ToString)
  lvi.SubItems.Add(myMatch1.Groups.Item(1).ToString)
  lvi.SubItems.Add(myMatch1.Groups.Item(1).ToString)
  lvi.SubItems.Add(myMatch1.Groups.Item(1).ToString)
  lvi.SubItems.Add(myMatch1.Groups.Item(1).ToString)
  lvi.SubItems.Add(myMatch1.Groups.Item(1).ToString)
  lvi.SubItems.Add(myMatch1.Groups.Item(1).ToString)
  Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited it to kind of match what you were already doing

I would do something like this (untested but should get you going):

```
Dim regMatch As New Regex("""(.*?)""")

For Each item as String in (the collection of strings you want to look through)
    Dim regMatches As MatchCollection = regMatch.Matches(item)
    Dim lvi As New ListViewItem()

    For x = 0 to 6
          lvi.SubItems.Add(regmatches(x).Value)
    Next
    lvi = ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
Next
```

Using .matches would be useful because it will esentially save the information into an array and since you have 7 things that you are matching, just use a for statement (0 to 6) to grab those things and to put them in the appopriate cells. Again, the syntax isn't perfect, but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a regular expression looking for the five groups:

```
Dim test As New WebClient
Dim s As String = test.DownloadString(TheStringIPosted)
For Each myMatch1 As Match In New Regex("""(.+?)"".+""(.+?)"".+""(.+?)"".+""(.+?)"".+""(.+?)"".+", RegexOptions.None).Matches(s)
  Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(myMatch1.Groups(1).Value)
  lvi.SubItems.Add(myMatch1.Groups(2).Value)
  lvi.SubItems.Add(myMatch1.Groups(3).Value)
  lvi.SubItems.Add(myMatch1.Groups(4).Value)
  lvi.SubItems.Add(myMatch1.Groups(5).Value)

  lvi = ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)

Next
```